# iOS: CIColorKernel applyWithExtent warning message

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

I'm trying to make original CIFilter with CIKernel.

code is here.

```
var kernel: CIKernel?
var inputImage: CIImage?

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.kernel = createKernel()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.kernel = createKernel()
}

func outputCustomImage() -> CIImage? {

    if let inputImage = self.inputImage {
        let dod = inputImage.extent.insetBy(dx: -1, dy: -1)
        let args = [inputImage as AnyObject]

        let callback: CIKernelROICallback = {
        (index, rect) in
            return rect.insetBy(dx: -1, dy: -1)
        }

        return kernel!.applyWithExtent(dod, roiCallback: callback, arguments: args)
    }
    return nil
}

private func createKernel() -> CIKernel {
    let kernelString =
        "kernel vec4 RGB_to_GBR(sampler source_image)\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "vec4 originalColor, twistedColor;\n" +
            "originalColor = sample(source_image, samplerCoord(source_image));\n" +
            "twistedColor.r = originalColor.g;\n" +
            "twistedColor.g = originalColor.b;\n" +
            "twistedColor.b = originalColor.r ;\n" +
            "twistedColor.a = originalColor.a;\n" +
            "return twistedColor;\n" +
    "}\n"

    return CIKernel(string: kernelString)!
}
```

and warning message is

> Note: CIColorKernel applyWithExtent:roiCallback:arguments: ignores callback and is not recomended.  Use applyWithExtent:arguments: instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe the source code you supplied is different to the code generating the warning. For the filter you're writing, you only need a `CIColorKernel` which would generate that warning if you're supplying an ROI callback.

A general kernel (`CIKernel`) is useful if you need to access other pixels - for example if you were writing a blur filter. Since you are only interested in the current pixel, stick with a color kernel and use `apply(withExtent:arguments:)`.

Generally, if you are subclassing `CIFilter`, you override `outputImage`. Take a look at this version (I've also simplified your kernel code):

```
class RGB_to_GBR: CIFilter {

    let kernel: CIColorKernel = {
        let kernelString =
            "kernel vec4 RGB_to_GBR(__sample pixel)\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "vec4 twistedColor = pixel.gbra;\n" +

            "return twistedColor;\n" +
        "}\n"

        return CIColorKernel(string: kernelString)!
    }()


    var inputImage: CIImage?

    override var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else {
            return nil
        }

        return kernel.apply(withExtent: inputImage.extent,
                            arguments: [inputImage])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I understood difference between CIKernel and CIColorKernel.

Comment: Also I found your book about Core Image. Its looks like very helpful, so I'll buy it :)